# Filter specific log messages using YAML file logging configuration

Tags: logging, yaml, logback, dropwizard

Ideally, I would like to prevent duplicate log messages by using YAML logging configuration. Something similar to TurboFilter class in logback

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#TurboFilter

```
<configuration> 
    <turboFilter 
      class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DuplicateMessageFilter">
        <AllowedRepetitions>2</AllowedRepetitions>
    </turboFilter>
</configuration>
```

If not possible, I would like to suppress/ filter/ redirect log messages from one specific class or log messages containing a specific string to a file location.

Answer (score 0):

TurboFilters are not supported in DropWizard logging at the moment. You would need to override the LoggingFactory with a custom one that reads the logback configuration file and then you can configure whatever you want. I have created a simple DW [project](https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/SOQ48815685) using this approach but basically you need to implement a LoggingFactory like this one:

```
public class SOQ48815685Logging implements LoggingFactory {

    @JsonIgnore
    private LoggerContext loggerContext;

    @JsonIgnore
    private final ContextInitializer contextInitializer;

    public SOQ48815685Logging() {

        this.loggerContext = LoggingUtil.getLoggerContext();

        this.contextInitializer = new ContextInitializer(loggerContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(MetricRegistry metricRegistry, String name) {

        try {

            contextInitializer.autoConfig();

        } catch (JoranException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

        loggerContext.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {

        loggerContext.reset();
    }
}
```

And then you need to override the "getLoggingFactory" method on your Configuration class:

```
public class SOQ48815685Configuration extends Configuration {

    @Override
    public synchronized LoggingFactory getLoggingFactory() {

        return new SOQ48815685Logging();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assuming that I can only change the yaml file and not the API, isn't it easier to add a logger specific configuration to suppress log messages from the class that is not needed? Something like this
`
#default log level
  level: WARN
  
  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:

    # Sets the level for  package 'com.test' to OFF.
    com.test: OFF
  
 (rest of the logging configuration)
...
`

Comment: Yes @rk666, that is correct. You can ignore log messages for a specific package/class using that approach. I have seen some issues in previous versions of DW where that syntax was not accepted despite it being in the official docs. I had to use com.test: level: OFF.